# Fast Reading of 10000 Binary Files?

Tags: python, linux

I have 10,000 binary files, named like this:

`file0.bin`

`file1.bin`

............
............

`file10000.bin`

Each of the above files contains exactly 391 float values (1564 bytes per file).

my goal is to read all of the files into a python array in the fastest way possible. If I open & close each file using a script, it takes a lot of time (about 8min!). 
are there any other creative ways to read these files FAST?

I am using Ubuntu Linux and would prefer a solution that can work with Python. Thanks.

Comment: Do it in parallel. I bet you are waiting a long time for seeks when opening each file.

Comment: 8 minutes for 15 MB - I don't think so.  What does your current script do?

Comment: AndiDog: my script just reads the files; NOTE: one file of 15MB is read in two secs! but because it is 10000 different files, it takes much more time

Comment: If your files are numbered `file0.bin` to `file10000.bin` then you actually have 10,001 files.

Comment: @ide: this would make sense if there is only one thread that does I/O -- and possibly another one that reads. If there is more than one read going on at the same, the alternating seeks will just slow things down.

Comment: 33 seconds with the most naive implementation (`a = array("f"); for each file: a.fromfile(file, 391)`). On a laptop hard disk. Definitely not 8 minutes.

Comment: And 1 second using C (`fopen`/`fread`).

Comment: The OPs files have to be bigger than 1K for the kind of performance he is complaining about.

Comment: @AndiDog: we get it, Python is slow. Sheesh

Comment: @kaloyan its not that slow granted I have a nice i7.

Comment: @kaloyan: Maybe, but I'm tempted to think that the OS/HDD will re-order reads as it sees fit.

Comment: I don't quite get why Python is so much slower in this case. Can't be OS file caching because that would apply to both Python and C based programs. As of `cProfile`, 99.9% of the time are spent in the 10000 `array.fromfile` calls (in my example), but looking at the source code, it doesn't do much more than a simple sequential read.

Comment: @user540009: what version of Python are you using? 3.1 and 2.7 due to backporting got a "A new version of the io library, rewritten in C for performance." Can this make a difference? http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html

Comment: Opening and closing 10001 files in Python takes my system 250ms.  Python won't be significantly slower here, because it's an I/O-bound operation.  Please post your code; something's wrong with it.

Comment: Maybe the files are on an NFS or other hard drive that's slow to access. Moving them to a local filesystem (like your `/tmp` directory) might speed things up.

Comment: This would have to be a _very_ slow filesystem (~32kB/sec). Even on a slow mechanical disk the seeks would expect worst case of 70 secs (10000 x 7msec). Perhaps the processing code is very slow?

Comment: I know this seems silly, but is it possible that the time being reported includes the time to start and stop Python, because each file is being processed independently?  On my notebook it takes about 0.04 s just to start python, import sys, and call sys.exit(), which if you do 10000 times takes 6-7 minutes, and that's roughly the right timing.

Comment: Have you tried to [`profile`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/profile.html) your code to find the bottleneck?

Answer (score 2):

If you want even faster make ramdisk:

```
# mkfs -q /dev/ram1 $(( 2 * 10000)) ## roughly the size you need
# mkdir -p /ramcache
# mount /dev/ram1 /ramcache
# df -H | grep ramcache
```

now concat

```
# cat file{1..10000}.bin >> /ramcache/concat.bin ## thanks SiegeX
```

Then let your script on that file

Since I haven't tested I prefixed everything with '#' so that you wouldn't have any accidents. Just remove them if you want it to work.

**This is an option but I would urge you to consider looking at the comments people have posted directly under your Q** 
You could probably get better results examining what you are doing wrong as I could not reproduce your speed problem of 8 mins.

Comment: I think you forgot a `cat` in there on the last line. Also, instead of a for loop, just `cat file{1..10000}.bin >> /ramcache/concat.bin`.

Comment: Thanks. using `#for f in *.bin; do $f >> /ramcache/concat.bin; done
` I am getting an error: "fileX.bin : command not found" for all files

Comment: I forgot cat. I updated my post. SO must have a delay cause I fixed that before you guys commented.

Comment: @Adam Also, `*.bin` doesn't guarantee file order (in case that matters) whereas my brace expansion version does.

Comment: @SiegeX I always forget the {...} bashfu. I usually do what I know for; do; done... one and done. Otherwise I spend like 15 minutes looking through man bash.

Comment: @Adam you forgot the `cat` again =) It was hiding at the end of the first line of my comment

Comment: Damn my multitasking... Thats what happens when you code and do other stuff.

Comment: @SiegeX: Actually `*.bin` is guaranteed to be in *lexical* order, but that's no good if you have unpadded numeric filenames, so the brace expansion *is* the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over them and use optimise flag you might also want to parse them using pypy it compiles python via a JIT compiler allowing for a somewhat marked increase in speed.

Answer (score 0):

You have 10001 files (0 to 10000 inclusive) and it takes 8 minutes to run the following?

```
try: xrange # python 2 - 3 compatibility
except NameError: xrange= range

import array

final= array.array('f')

for file_seq in xrange(10001):
    with open("file%d.bin" % file_seq, "rb") as fp:
        final.fromfile(fp, 391)
```

What's the underlying filesystem? How much RAM do you have? What's your processor and its speed?